# Access a new UIViewController from a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Tab Bar application with 6 Tab Bar items that each open a UITableView. I am trying to enable each table with the ability to open a Detail View Controller when an item in a row on the table is selected.

For example, for the first ViewController ( `ViewController1.m` ), I created

```
DetailView1.xib
DetailViewController1.h
DetailViewController1.m
```

In order to get each row in ViewController1.m 's TableView, I understand I must 
use this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

This is my code for that method, which does not produce any errors or warnings, but nothing sees to happen when the TableViewCell is selected:

```
DetailViewController1 *dvController = [[DetailViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[navController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
[dvController release];
```

Should this not load DetailView1.xib? I created this with the Tab Bar Application Template...which has no NavigationController in it by default I believe. Is it possible something is not hooked up right in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to configure each tab to contain an instance of `UINavigationController` with one of your view controllers nested inside of it. Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you'd want to change the second line of code in your example to this:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
```